# awk for date ranges date format like mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: awk

I have my log file like this i am trying retrive date range

```
"07/10/2013 01:31:54","SNMP" 

"07/10/2013 01:31:54","SNMP" 
.... ... .. 
"07/10/2013 03:03:54","SNMP"
```

I am using fallowing awk command, it gives all the rows, i tried different combination no use, is there standard data format need to use in awk?

```
awk -F, '"07/10/2013 01:35:40" > $1&&$1 <= "07/10/2013 01:50:03"' Mylog.log | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems: *CSV parsing* and *date comparison*.

The first one you can solve using `match()`, or a [CSV parsing function](http://lorance.freeshell.org/csv/).

The second one you can solve by either using a proper date format like [ISO-8601](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html), a happy side-effect being that dates (ex timezone/DST changes) can be compared lexically. 
If you are really using `gawk` instead of plain `awk` or `nawk` you can use the built-in date function `mktime()` to parse timestamps and return an epoch-second ordinal which allows dates to be compared numerically.
`awk` has no native date/time types, and no standard data/time libraries, so lexical or numeric comparisons are the most straightforward option here.

A final option with `gawk` is a nasty hack:

```
/^"07.10.2013 01:35:40"/,/^"07.10.2013 01:50:03"/ {
    # your code here
}
```

This uses a [range expression](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gawk_toc.html#SEC55) to limit the scope of matching to between certain lines. This should work for your file format as long as the times are monotonic increasing – this is *not* true for Apache logs (since they are logged in order of completion, but by default contain the original request time stamp, and are not guaranteed to be monotonic increasing).

Answer (score 1):

String compare:

```
$ awk -F" '"07/10/2013 01:35:40" > $2 && $2 <= "07/10/2013 01:50:03"' file
"07/10/2013 01:31:54","SNMP"
"07/10/2013 01:31:54","SNMP"
.... ... ..
```

... seems to work! To compare times better use `mktime("YYYY MM DD HH MM SS")` .