# Importing only rows matching specific values

Tags: r

I am new to R and am using `read.csv` to import a dataset. The dataset I am working with is available here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00235/. Instead of importing the entire dataset and then subsetting out what I need, I would like to import only the portion I need from the get-go. The first column in the dataset is titled "Date" and I only need the data corresponding to the first week of April 2007. To read the entire dataset, I can do as follows:

```
initial <- read.table("household_power_consumption.txt", sep = ";", nrows = 100)
classes <- sapply(initial, class)
powerconsumption <- read.table(file = "household_power_consumption.txt",colClasses = classes, sep = ";", header = TRUE, col.names = c("Date", "Time", "Global_active_power", "Global_reactive_power", "Voltage", "Global_intensity", "Sub_metering_1", "Sub_metering_2", "Sub_metering_3"))
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a workaround for `?read.table` to allow for importing only a subset of the dataset, something like this:

```
powerconsumption <- read.table(file = "household_power_consumption.txt",colClasses = classes, sep = ";", header = TRUE, col.names = c("Date", "Time", "Global_active_power", "Global_reactive_power", "Voltage", "Global_intensity", "Sub_metering_1", "Sub_metering_2", "Sub_metering_3"), col = (Date==c("1/2/2007", "2/7/2007")))
```

Notice the addition of `, col = (Date==c("1/2/2007", "2/7/2007")))`.

Comment: If the data isn't extremely large, you could try `read.table(...)[subset]`.  No guarantee that'll work the way you want it to though. Or, if you're familiar with the shell and its command line (specifically `cut`, `sed`, `awk`), you can subset the file to a new file then import the new file into R

Comment: Also, if you know where the information you need is in the data, the argument `skip` used with `nrows` in `read.table()` can be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read.table` function does quite a bit of processing and can bog down with large files unless you do as you already demonstrate use colClasses.  So if you only want a small subset it might probably be to your advantage to select a few rows from an "undigested" version. You can do this in two ways. The fasted would probably be to do external processing with sed or awk. Here's a [link doing data comparison in awk.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566517/awk-for-date-ranges-date-format-like-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss) I will, however, show you how to do it with R. I'm going to take you naturla language request for "first week in April 2007 and assume that your dates are not in POSIX-standard format, but rather n/n/nnnn format and that there are no leading zeros.

```
 Lines <- readLines("household_power_consumption.txt")
 subL <- grep("^[1234567]/5/2007", substr(Lines, 1,8)  # a numeric vector
 inSub <- read.table(text=Lines[subL,,], header = TRUE, col.names = c("Date", "Time", "Global_active_power", "Global_reactive_power", "Voltage", "Global_intensity", "Sub_metering_1", "Sub_metering_2", "Sub_metering_3"))
```

I'm afraid I'm not willing to download a 20MB file to answer this question, so you can either post a better description or `head()` from your 'initial' data-object